# Text is breaking using absolute positioning, part 2

Tags: html, css, line-breaks, absolute

This question refers to this one : [Text is breaking using absolute positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680940/text-is-breaking-using-absolute-positioning)

Answers of this one recommend to use `white-space: nowrap;`

My case is exactly the same (I don't know the width of the title div **and I dont want to set it**), but I do not want my text to be systematically on a single line either.

My title has a `max-width: 300px` and I would like the content to be on a single line until it reaches this max-width, after that, I would like to have a line break and start over on a other one. (dont know if I am clear enough).
In this case, `white-space: nowrap;` is useless ...

Here is a codepen : https://codepen.io/msieurtoph/pen/wjKNZZ

How can I do to make this

[image]

or this

[image]

... look like :

[image]

?

Thanks for any help

Comment: try adding `min-width:80%` to the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're having is the way you're centering an absolute positioned div of unknown width using transform / translate.  The `left: 50%` rule effectively gives your title a max width of 50% of the parent because the browser sees it as beginning in the middle and extending to the right edge.

My solution is to wrap the title in a full width absolutely positioned div and then centering it using `text-align: center` on the parent and `display: inline-block` on the child.  This will allow the h2 element to expand dynamically up to your max-width but still collapse if the content doesn't require it.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 60px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  border: 3px double black;
  padding-top: 60px;
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
}

.content p {
  margin: 20px;
}

.title {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.title h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>February 2015 and real long text</h1>
  </div>
  <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma
    pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the transform/translate and white-space, u can set it to absolute positioning with left and top,changing the max-width:90%,

```css
/* Cosmetics */
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body { margin: 60px; }
p { margin: 0; }


/* True Code */
.content {
  border: 3px double black;
  padding-top: 60px;
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
}

.content p { margin: 20px; }

.title {
 background: black;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: red;
 left: 16px;
 padding: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 top: -40px;
 max-width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1 class="title">February 2015 and real long text</h1>
  <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not stay centered with smaller amount of text

Comment: @billynoah is right. if there is only one word or two, the div is not centered.